# Continuation-Passing Style in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, continuation-passing

I ran into this code [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style):

```
(define (pyth x y k)
    (* x x (lambda (x2)
        (* y y (lambda (y2)
            (+ x2 y2 (lambda (x2py2)
                (sqrt x2py2 k))))))))
```

The article says that that code is the Continuation-Passing version of another piece of code:

```
(define (pyth x y)
    (sqrt (+ (* x x) (* y y))))
```

However, I'm quite confused: How does that even work? How do you multiply a number by a lambda here? `(* x x (lambda ...))`

Comment: Elegant weapons for a more civilized age.

Comment: Just ran into your question after posting a [similar one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38611717/1488067). Good news is that the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) has been updated in the meantime to use `*&`, `+&` and `sqrt&`, i.e. a convention where an ampersand is appended to each function which accepts a continuation as the last parameter. It took me a while nevertheless to understand that these functions are not part of Scheme's standard operators, but implemented explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Wikipedia example, `*` doesn't mean the same thing as `*` in the conventional example.

I would rewrite the Wikipedia example as:

```
(define (pyth x y k)
    (cps-* x x (lambda (x2)
        (cps-* y y (lambda (y2)
            (cps-+ x2 y2 (lambda (x2py2)
                (cps-sqrt x2py2 k))))))))
```

In this form, each of the `cps-xxx` functions perform the operation indicated and then pass the result to the last argument. You could call it like this:

```
(pyth 2 3 display)
```

which would multiply 2 and 3, giving 6, and then passing 6 to `display`. (Actually you would want to pass the result to a `cps-display` that displayed its initial argument(s) and then called *another* function specified as its last parameter).

Comment: More specifically, for people who want to actually try this out: (define (cps-* x y k) (k (* x y)), (define (cps-+ x y k) (k (+ x y))), and (define (cps-sqrt n k) (k (sqrt n))).

Comment: Gotcha... that asterisk in the article is **very** misleading; thanks a lot for clarifying that! :)

Comment: In CPS every function has one (or more) extra parameter for the continuation. Multiply and add are normal functions ...